# select from database with special characters

Tags: php

I am using php

```
select * from `outstanding` where `lcocode`='PN007\00128'

select * from `outstanding` where `lcocode` LIKE 'PN007\00128'
```

kindly suggest code for fetching data with backslash

I used above code but did not got results.

Comment: You tagged this [tag:sql]. Did you mean [tag:sql-server]?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following query :

```
select * from outstanding where lcocode LIKE 'PN007\\\\00128'
```

Backslash is an escape prefix for both strings and LIKE patterns. So you need to double it once for LIKE, and again for string literal syntax.